# developing a windows app

Tags: windows, exe

I want to develop an app for windows that will end up being an exe file and have an installation process. However, I dont know where to start or which steps to follow. What is the best language to use and how do I endup having an exe file ?

Comment: [How is `exe` formed ? How program get installed](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your easiest approach is to download MS Visual Studio Express for C#. If you want a GUI app then use the WinForms framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know programming, but, I'll assume you don't.

Basically, to make a GUI (graphical user interface) application for Windows, you must use the Win32 API or something built "on top" (i.e. abstracts from) of it.

You can do this with C++ directly or with .NET (a thing that makes life easier for you).

For .NET, you can use multiple languages, such as Visual Basic and C#, I recommend you start with C# and then go from there.